# RF ground capacitor broken off on Raspberry Pi 4 - How does it affect performance?

Tags: capacitor, rf, raspberry-pi, surface-mount

Observe the following image:

[image]

A small SMD capacitor near the J4 display connector has broken off on my Raspberry Pi 4 Model B.

WiFi appears to function normally on the 5GHz band, but I'm very curious about the purpose of this capacitor, and how it may affect the performance of the RF hardware on there. I found a [reduced schematic](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/schematics/rpi_SCH_4b_4p0_reduced.pdf) of the board, but I can't even find which component this is. The silkscreen on the board doesn't label it either.
Any information would be lovely. From what I can tell, it seems like the two capacitors placed next to each other in the original circuit are bridging across (presumably) two grounding planes, but I have no idea how that would affect functionality of the circuitry here.

Comment: It's a resonant cavity antenna. However, the feed is at the two caps in the middle of the triangle on this board, so those caps on the edge are most likely for trimming a director element. Try to resolder it.

Answer (score 0):

There's a fair chance they're bypass caps, between a ground plane and a power plane.  Bypass caps are almost always required, and used liberally due to their low cost...so losing one *probably* won't result in performance issues.  It may affect EMC, but most likely you wouldn't notice that difference outside a testing lab.

This entire analysis is based on the assumption that your broken cap is indeed for supply bypassing.